# My products in the category page can't display in magento2.4.5 with the FreeGo theme

Tags: php, magento, magento2.4

I applied the FreeGo theme and everything is fine, but I can't display my products in the category page.
I found that there is no toolbar.phtml and limiter.phtml in the downloaded theme folder. These seem to be files related to product display. I don’t know if they are related?
Thank you, hope this problem can be solved.

I try to edit limiter.phtml, because I found the other question have this problem.
But,there is no this file...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had the same problem, hope someone fine the answer

Answer (score 1):

**I found the solution**
After checking logs I found that there is some errors preventing page from load.

You have to go to this file `\app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml` line `53`.

It will be like this:

```
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
```

Edit it to be:

```
$pos = $block->getPositioned(); /* because this function is not working */
$pos = " grid-primary";         /* don't remove the space before grid */
```

---

In Same file line `127` and `244`, you will find this line:

```
$special_price = number_format($_product->getSpecialPrice(), 2);
```

This Also making some errors, so fixing it to

```
$special_price = number_format(floatval($_product->getSpecialPrice()), 2);
```

Then don't forget to **clear cache** to apply the changes

Enjoy ♥

Comment: Very helpful! I also had errors with $regular_price on the line below, so used the same floatval fix.